# HighChart : Showing Some Data After the Grid Lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I  have a linechart made using highchart.

There will only be certain number of values only in Y axis and have to show some data after the grid ends.

**Expected Results:**
[image]

**Current Implementation:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Data Table Example'
  },

  chart: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    spacingBottom: 30
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  series: [{
    data: [0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2],
  }],
  exporting: {
    showTable: true
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="container" class="col-sm-8"></div>
  <div id="grid" class="col-sm-4">


    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Count</th>
          <th>%</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>44</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>



  </div>
</div>
```

We need to make sure that it remains responsive for all the different devices. The table I have created behaves fine for some specific resolution.

Comment: I do not fully understand your expectations, should the table and chart always be in one line? Can you adapt this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qm4fbx0h/, to your result?

Comment: I want to display some information opposite to Y axis but within the grid lines.

Comment: e.g.  jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qm4fbx0h has 4 grid lines for y = 1 , y=2, y=3 and y=4 so I want to display something on opposite side of Y axis between these grid lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always have the same positions of gridLines and table lines, you can calculate the height for each table row based on yAxis tick position.

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var chart = this,
                ticks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks,
                rows = $(".table").find("tr"),
                heights = [];

            Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(tick, i) {
                heights.push(tick.gridLine.d.split(' ')[2]);
            });

            heights.reverse();

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (i === rows.length - 1) {
                    $(rows[i]).css('height', chart.chartHeight - heights[heights.length - 1])
                } else if (i > 0) {
                    $(rows[i]).css('height', heights[i] - heights[i - 1])
                } else {
                    $(rows[i]).css('height', heights[i])
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/avgb1cu0/

Comment: Seems like this is what I wanted, just one more query. If we zoom in the table block goes below the chart. Can we make sure that it always remains inline with the graph.

Comment: Use bootstrap 'col-xs-' class for columns. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/51xrd6ps/